How do you change the Magento (Community) 2.4.7 Admin Login page logo
I want to change the admin login screen logo on my 2.4.7 install.
I've followed every guide, and tried every answer I can find.
Only have a basic knowledge of Magento backend.
Can anyone see the mistake there must be in my theme and module files?
(I've replaced my vendor name and theme name with placeholders, but have tried carefully following other guides using their naming.)
Commands:
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento cache:clean

Magento is set to developer mode.
design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > theme.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>

design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > registration.php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'adminhtml/vendor/theme', __DIR__);

Logo File:
design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > Magento_Backend > web > images > adminlogin-logo.png
design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > Magento_Backend > layout > admin_login.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/adminlogin-logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
                <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">80</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>

code > vendor > theme > registration.php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'vendor_theme', __DIR__);

code > vendor > theme > etc > di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">vendor/Theme</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
</config>

code > vendor > theme > etc > module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="vendor_theme">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence> 
    </module> 
</config>

Any mostly beginner help appreciated! :)

It seems you're doing it right, except the logo file path.

Admin Logo Image file should be in the THEME path. It doesn't consider
the Theme Module Path

So place the admin logo inside the theme root path and deploy the static content, as shown below.
app > design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > web > images > adminlogin-logo.png

you can notice it's web/images not Magento_Backend > web > images

In case if you still can't get your admin logo displayed, as an alternate, you can also keep the same logo path as you specified and follow the steps below
design > adminhtml > vendor > theme > Magento_Backend > web > images > adminlogin-logo.png

create a layout file default.xml inside
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout
and add these configuration in the layout default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @copyright (c) 2024
 * @author Jerome Dennis <jerome@transformmerce.com>
 * @category Vendor
 * @package Vendor_theme
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/images/adminlogin-logo.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

If you still can't get the logo debug the block template header.phtml in the file path
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page
This file can also be overridden inside your custom admin theme and below are the code used to render the admin logo and you can debug and watch the variable $logoSrc which checks whether block argument has_logo_src has some value and use it, else it defaults to the magento logo.
<?php $logoSrc = ($block->hasLogoImageSrc()) ? $block->escapeHtml($block->getLogoImageSrc()) : 'images/magento-logo.svg' ?>
        <a
            href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getHomeLink()) ?>"
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $edition ?>
            class="logo">
            <img class="logo-img" src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getViewFileUrl($logoSrc) ?>"
            alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Magento Admin Panel')) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Magento Admin Panel')) ?>"/>
        </a>


Thank you for the feedback! Sadly, I've actually already tried that path for the logo with no luck - I've tried again, just in case but still nothing. My header.phtml file is slightly different. I'm wondering if my issue is the bitnami packaged Magento install I'm using. Perhaps something is going wrong there.
I've also notice, if i force a static content deploy, I get this error:
Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed in /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Simple.php:59 that's just one line, same theme_dir error on multiple. :(

app/code/Vendor_name/Module_Name/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/logo-white.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

put your logo file in this directory:
magento/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/images/logo-white.png

I understood that it's better practice not to edit any of the core Magento folders/files? Does this modification get reset when you upgrade to the next Magento version on it's release for example?
